# Calling external user control by its name

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls, panel

I have  one panel (`Panel1`), two combo boxes (`ComboBox1`, `ComboBox2`) and one  button (`Button1`) all in same form (`Form1`).

When the button is clicked:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   Dim a as String = ComboBox1.SelectedValue() & Combobox2.SelectedValue()
   AddUserControl(a)
End Sub
```

value of `a` is the name of an external user control for instance `p1k1`.
Can I add an external user control named `p1k1` to `Panel1` in `Form1` using following method?

```
Private Sub AddUserControl(ByVal a As String)
    Panel1.Controls.Add(a)
End Sub
```

What should I do to make this work?

Usually I would use:

```
Panel1.Controls.Add(new p1k1)
```

Comment: Have you looked at here? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx) to do this.  Something like this:

```
    Private Sub AddUserControl(ByVal a As String)
        Dim controlType As Type = Type.GetType(a)
        If controlType Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentException(String.Format("""{0}"" is not a valid type.  Type names are case sensitive.", a))
        ElseIf Not controlType.IsSubclassOf(GetType(Control)) Then
            Throw New ArgumentException(String.Format("""{0}"" does not inherit from Control.  Only Controls can be added to the control collection.", a))
        End If

        Dim newControl As Control = Activator.CreateInstance(controlType)
        If newControl Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentException(String.Format("Unspecified error when creating control of type ""{0}"".", a))
        End If
        Panel1.Controls.Add(newControl)
    End Sub
```

Comment: i got null value for newControl variable

Comment: That means either: 1) The String referred to by "a" was not a valid type name or 2) The type does not inherit from Control (and thus cannot be added to the Control collection).  Check the edited code where I've added simple type checking.

Comment: exception number 1 is appear, is not a valid type name... How to resolve this? My usercontrol file name in my project solution is p1k1.vb .... why it is said as not a valid type name ?

Answer (score 0):

i found my answer finally...

> Private Sub AddUserControl(ByVal a As String)
>   Dim nmspace As String = "mynamespace"
>   Dim t As Type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(nmspace & "." & a)
>   Dim o As Control = Activator.CreateInstance(t)
>   Panel1.Controls.Add(o)
>   End Sub